# Sanitize a Variable & integrate php code with Jquery Validation for form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a piece of code for checking if a "user already exists" in my database and i was told that the code is outdated as get_magic_quotes_gpc no longer works and my username variable is not sanitized .

I tried to update the code but not sure if its ok :

Original :

```
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);

    }

     $usercheck = $_POST['username'];

     $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$usercheck'") 

     or die(mysql_error());

     $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);


if ($check2 != 0) {

die('Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');

                }
```

UPDATED :

// i already have a jquery validation that checks it is a word (\w+) before submitting

```
  $usercheck = $_POST['username'];

    $sanitizeduser= filter_var($usercheck, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

    $check = mysqli_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $sanitizeduser)"

    if ($check != 0) {

        die('Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');

                }
```

---

I also want to check it first with jquery before submitting the form - i already have a jquery code for testing valid name , email etc.. but i don;t know how to include that php code inside of it since i have to access the db.

parts of my jquery code : ( i'm using this script : http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
names: function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/.test(value);
        },
```

if it returns true - i get a valid message , 
returns false - get a custom message

Full Jquery code :

file 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/EjSbd/1/ (script.js)

file 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/qM4Uz/1/ (jquery.validate.js)

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten quotes for `$sanitizeduser` in the query. Also, what happens if the user enters quotes? Client side validation is great for weeding out typos but if someone **wants** to send something to your server, _JavaScript_ won't stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql_real_escape_string() function for server side.

Javascript is fine for client side and user can disable javascript from the browser so at that time javascript validation will not work. So dont rely on only javascript validation. Use server side escaping also to filter the user data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

And dont rely on any javascript preventing anything,
attackers wont even use a browser to attack you.